# How to increase the volume in an m4a file?

Tags: audio, m4a

I have an m4a file. When listening to it on my iPod Touch, the volume is too low, even when I turn it all the way up.

I need to increase the volume in the file so that I can hear what is being said.

Also, in the background it sounds like there is a hissing sound that I'd like to get rid of.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `m4v`, not "`m4b`"?

Comment: try [audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 5):

I'd use [mp3gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/) or [AACGAIN](http://www.rarewares.org/aac-encoders.php#aacgain) for that. The former's GUI works with AACGAIN too, but AACGAIN is the app for m4as.

It'll let you batch modify the volume of files to a certain level without loss of quality.

Comment: From looking at the web page for mp3gain, it looks like it's for averaging the volume of a set of MP3 files. Can it adjust the volume of a single file?

Comment: The mp3gain application fails to process my m4a files. I assume this tool is intended to be used with MP3 files, not m4a files.

Comment: As per the answer - it's mp4gain but the mp3gain GUI can use that. It's been over a decade though since I posted the answer so I am hazy on the details

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at "Auto Volume Levelling". This is done on your PC/MAC.

[This page](http://www.jakeludington.com/ask_jake/20041124_auto_volume_leveling_for_music.html) has instructions for iTunes as well as other music apps.

Though if you've got a background hiss already, this could get louder too. You'd need to look at some more serious filtering software for that.